# Having my application launch a network volume upon launch

Tags: macos, cocoa

Just starting out with ObjC and Xcode.

I would like my application to connect/mount an AFP network volume upon launch (the credentials are already saved to the keychain of the computer).  I realize that I need to place this code here:

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

XXX

}

Except Im not quite sure what needs to go here?!

I have learned that FSMountVolume is now deprecated, and it wants to see NSURL, except Im not sure how to implement this - I'm so new that I am having a hard time understanding how to read and implement the Xcode documentation...

Does anyone know of a quick and dirty way to do this?

Comment: I guess DADiskMount() or DADiskMountWithArguments() from the DiskArbitration Framework is the designated successor, but other than some header files there doesn't appear to be much info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little program that should mount the drive. It compiles and works on my computer, but I do not have any spaces in my afp path. Let me know if this works:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <NetFS/NetFS.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSURL * share = [NSURL URLWithString: @"afp://user@server_ip/share"];
        NSURL * path = [NSURL URLWithString: @"/path/to/mount/point/"];
        CFURLRef share2 = (__bridge CFURLRef) share;
        CFURLRef path2 = (__bridge CFURLRef) path;
        CFArrayRef mountpoints = NULL;

        NetFSMountURLSync(share2, path2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &mountpoints);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I just swap the "smb" with "afp"?

Comment: Hey Bogdan...

This is the fault Im getting when I attempt to you use suggestion:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NetFSMountURLSync", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The only framework that I have imported into the header file is the following:

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> (imported by default) 
#import <NetFS/NetFS.h> (as you suggested)

Any suggestions?  Do I need to import CoreFoundation too?

Comment: Cancel that...

I think I just needed to add the netFS framework!  It seems to be working better now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This now appears to mount the server and prompts the user to select a share point (not ideal), but when I select the share I want Xcode pauses the running application and switches to "Thread View" and points out:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Still could use some help!

Comment: Hmm, in the URL do you specify both the server and the share? The format is: "afp://server/share". It should only prompt for the share if you did not specify it. Also, check that the directory specified in mountDir exists and is writable by the user.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"afp://10.99.131.13/Volumes/Audio/ELEMENT LIBRARY/ ProTools Preference Storage"];
    NSString *netUser = @"XXXXX";
    NSString *netPass = @"XXXXX";
    
    
    NetFSMountURLSync((__bridge CFURLRef) url, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) netUser, (__bridge CFStringRef) netPass, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  
}

In this case I have added the mountpoint to the URL.  In this scenario it doesn't prompt, but the outcome is the same :( Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: I have also tried as you suggest (with a simple URL & a share-point).  When I do this it DOES prompt the user to connect to a share for some reason.  Either way once the desired share is selected it kicks the same thread error.  I've also tried the same block of code in a button push, rather than in applicationDidFinishLaunching.  Same fault if I remove the user credentials (or just don't call them).  I've even tried a different server.

Comment: To answer your original question the specified share is readable/writeable by the user.  Do I need to "return" something to close this off, it almost feels as though the application is say, now what?

Comment: ...Also, don't I need to alloc memory to these variables that use pointers?

Comment: Try to compile the little program that I posted in the updated answer above. Let me know if it kicks any errors, it doesn't in my case, and works well. Let me know if it works for you. That function returns an error number, but you don't have to read it, unless you want to display it to the user. I was having segmentation errors, because the last var actually needed to be not NULL. That return the mount point on success. You can look at the NetFS.h for a lot more info on that function. To be on a safe side, pass it the afp path with the user name in it. Like this: afp://user@server_ip/share